# My RSA decryption doesnt match answer

Tags: encryption, rsa, decryption

Break the RSA code whose key is $(n, e) = (8369428283, 1234567)$.

Find the deciphering key and then decipher the message under the assumption that the plaintext consists of 7-letter blocks in the alphabet, converted to an integer between 0 and 26^(7) −1 in the usual way, and the ciphertext consists of 8-letter blocks in the same alphabet.

The given answer was `CLAIMYOURPRIZE`, but this doesn't match the one I got.

I converted the first 7-Letter block in `CLAIMYOURPRIZE` and I also got the first 8-letter block of the encrypted message. Then in order for them to match the value of the private key (d) must be 2 and that is not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- $n = 8369428283 = 81799×102317$ (2 distinct prime factors by [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor%208369428283))

The $d$ can be found in two ways;

1. if [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) $\varphi(n)= (p-1)(q-1) = 8369244168$ is used then

   - $d = 5788687615 = e^{-1} \bmod 8369244168$
2. If [Carmichael Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) $\lambda(n) = \text{LCM}(p-1,q-1) = 4184622084$ is used then

   - $d=1604065531 = e^{-1}  \bmod 4184622084$

Carmichael Function $\lambda$ provides us the smallest $d$  ([lcm versus phi in RSA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/29591/18298)) and this can be helpful for reducing the timing of decrypting and signing. Here, $d$ calculated with $\lambda(n)$ is two-bit less than $d$ calculated with $\varphi(n)$.

I've encrypted end decrypted both parts by $\varphi(n)$ and $\lambda$ successfully.

```
[ C =  2 ][ L = 11 ][ A =  0 ][ I =  8 ][ M = 12 ][ Y = 24 ][ O = 14 ]
plaintext       =     CLAIMYO
plaintext int   =   748676046

ciphertext int  =  1773907495
ciphertext char =    AFTHVVNJ
plaintext char  =     CLAIMYO

[ U = 20 ][ R = 17 ][ P = 15 ][ R = 17 ][ I =  8 ][ Z = 25 ][ E =  4 ]
plaintext       =     URPRIZE
plaintext int   =  6387458406

ciphertext int  =  5283907511
ciphertext char =    ARCSTZFZ
plaintext char  =     URPRIZE
```

**note:** the `A` in the ciphertext means 0 as an integer.

Comment: Hey Kelalaka thank you for the help today, I finally was able to get the correct answer, there was a bug in my code at the final step. I now also get CLAIMYOURPRIZE as the answer.